# The bind method of javascript seems not working as expected

Tags: javascript, this, bind, iife

```js
var obj = {
    say: function() {
        function _say() {
            console.log(this);
        }
        return _say.bind(obj);
    }()
};

obj.say();
```

the code result is log out the global or window, I want to know why the bind method doesn't bind 'this' to the obj object context?

Comment: The real question here is if you need `this` binding, why are you not using an actual object-with-prototype? The code you show tries to ladle "instance logic" into "instance-of-nothing" code, which you *can* do, it's JavaScript, but it's also really... silly? What are you *actually* trying to do with this code? (or with code like this)

Comment: (1) Put a breakpoint on the `return _say.bind(obj);` line. (2) When it stops there, examine the value of `obj`. (3) Think real hard. (4) Explain to your [rubber ducky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) exactly why you are trying to assign the result of an IIFE to the property `say`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans. This code is a just practice, I want to know why 'this' is global when using bind(undefined).

Comment: it's a reasonable question if you're spec diving, but the code you show is worth never using in any real file you intent to actually work with, or worse, have others work on =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During assignment the variable `obj` still does not have any value. As such, your call to bind is equivalent to `.bind(undefined)` which behaves the way you observed.

To be more specific, `this` referring to `window` is because of [OrdinaryCallBindThis](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-ordinarycallbindthis) doing the following steps (non strict mode):

```
[...]
If thisArgument is undefined or null, then
[...]
Let thisValue be globalEnvRec.[[GlobalThisValue]].
```

You can check in the chrome debugger that `[[BoundThis]]` is indeed `undefined` after your call.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @ASDGerte. But if the _say function bind 'this' to 'undefined', why the 'this' in the obj.say() bind to global/window instead of obj?

Comment: @smallbone edited. I was just searching for that after answering as well :)

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking the function immediately. Remove parenthesis following `say` function. If you are expecting to call the function without two consecutive parenthesis `obj.say()()` use `.call()` instead of `.bind()`

```js
var obj = {
  say: function() {
    function _say() {
      console.log(this);
    }
    return _say.call(this);
  }
};

obj.say();
```